# Google Sheets Problem w/ Substring Replacement Text Using =Left

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, character-replacement

Trying to fix some malformed data. Here is the formula I'm using:

```
={"Final Name";ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(E3:E),,LEFT(E3:E,find(".",E3:E)-2))))}
```

Here is a sample of the data in colE. The list indent is not part of the data, it's just formating here for readability. I'm guessing I need some regex or something here but that's a little beyond my scope.

- CeeDee LambC. Lamb DAL
- J.K. DobbinsJ. Dobbins BAL
- Anthony McFarland Jr.A. McFarland PIT
- Michael Warren IIM. Warren PHI

The first produces CeeDee Lamb. That's perfect. The rest of them are not working - which is to be expected but I don't know how to fix.

- **What I want it produce is: J.K. Dobbins**
- What it actually produces is: (Blank Cell)
- **What I want it to produce is: Anthony McFarland**
- What it actually produces is: Anthony McFarland J
- **What I want it to produce is: Michael Warren**
- What it actually produces is: Michael Warren II

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(A1:A, " "), 9^9, 2))),, 9^9)), "[A-Z]?\.$", ))
```

[image]